# Fundamental error when assuming "per unit Celsius" = "per unit kelvin"

Tags: temperature, unit

While doing a chemical engineering question today, I came across something quite fundamental that I can't seem to get my head around.

I had a value in *bar/°C*, and I had to multiply it by a temperature to receive a value in *bar*. Naturally, the temperature I multiply by is in Celsius as well. However, if I wanted to convert this temperature to kelvin, I would add 273.15 to the temperature value as normal. I would also typically state that the value in *bar/°C* is equal to *bar/K*, and Google is in agreement. Therefore, I would obtain a completely different answer when converting to kelvin than when I stayed in Celsius, as the temperature increases by 273.15 while the value in *bar/K* is unchanged. The answer is in bar regardless, but with completely different values.

How can this be explained? Is *bar/°C* not actually equal to *bar/K*?

Answer (score 3):

You should be multiplying by ΔT, not the numeric value of T. Otherwise with zero or negative °C you would get nonsense results.

$\Delta T = T_1 - T_2$ will then be the same in Celsius and kelvin.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you have a pressure rise stated in bar/°C and the rise is from 20°C to 25°C then you multiply by 5.

If the pressure rise is given as bar/K then based on the difference will be the same.

However if you are not working with a difference then you need to recalculate for a pressure value to be per K as 25°C is equivalent (25 + 273.13) = 298.13 K so the pressure value will be much smaller...